# Show images one after one after some interval of time

Tags: javascript, html

I am new person in Front End Development and i am facing one major problem is that i have 3 images placed on each others and now i want to move one image so the other image comes up and then it goes and third image comes up after some interval of time.

I want three images on same position in my site but only wants to see these three images one after one after some interval of time.
Please help how i can do this??

May i use marquee property or javascript???

Comment: I have added pure JS solution, I will later add some effect to it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go PURE JavaScript solution:

**EDIT** I have added image rotation... Check out live example (link below)

```
<script>

    var current = 0;
    var rotator_obj = null;

    var images_array = new Array();
    images_array[0] = "rotator_1";
    images_array[1] = "rotator_2";
    images_array[2] = "rotator_3";

    var rotate_them = setInterval(function(){rotating()},4000);

    function rotating(){

        rotator_obj = document.getElementById(images_array[current]);

        if(current != 0) {

            var rotator_obj_pass = document.getElementById(images_array[current-1]);
            rotator_obj_pass.style.left = "-320px";

        }
        else {

            rotator_obj.style.left = "-320px";

        }

        var slideit = setInterval(function(){change_position(rotator_obj)},30);

        current++;

        if (current == images_array.length+1) {

            var rotator_obj_passed = document.getElementById(images_array[current-2]);
            rotator_obj_passed.style.left = "-320px";
            current = 0;
            rotating();

        }

    }

    function change_position(rotator_obj, type) {

        var intleft = parseInt(rotator_obj.style.left);

        if (intleft != 0) {

            rotator_obj.style.left = intleft + 32 + "px";

        }
        else if (intleft == 0) {

            clearInterval(slideit);

        }

    }


</script>

<style>

    #rotate_outer {

        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 320px;
        height: 240px;
        margin-top: -120px;
        margin-left: -160px;
        overflow: hidden;

    }

    #rotate_outer img {

        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;

    }

</style>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="rotating();">

    <div id="rotate_outer">
        <img src="0.jpg" id="rotator_1"  style="left: -320px;" />
        <img src="1.jpg" id="rotator_2"  style="left: -320px;" />
        <img src="2.jpg" id="rotator_3"  style="left: -320px;" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**And a working example:**
http://simplestudio.rs/yard/rotate/rotate.html

Comment: I'd suggest having all 3 images and hide/show as needed. Changing the source may cause the browser to ask for the images again to make sure it's cached version is up-to-date

Comment: You are right, in that way I could easy make transition animation. I wrote this fast, I will modify it for sure!

Comment: Never fear, I have downn below :D

Comment: I have edited my answer now it has transition animation, you can work more on it to add some other effects like rotating images in a loop etc. I hope I gave you a clue where to start...

Comment: I added image rotation loop so that now it's rotating until the ned of time :)

Answer (score 4):

**Non-jQuery Option**

If you don't want to go down the jquery route, you can try http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider. The setup is just as easy, you just have to make sure that your images are in a div with id of `slider` and that div has the same dimensions as one of your images.

---

**jQuery Option**

The [jQuery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) will help you achieve this. It requires jquery to work but it doesn't need much setting up to create a simple sliple slideshow.

Have a look at the ['super basic' demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/basic.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
```

It has [many options](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) if you want something a bit fancier.

Comment: Please do not suggest the use of an entire library unless quite a bit more than a single operation from it is to be used.

Comment: I think that for a beginner, this is the easiest way to achieve what the OP is after. I could give him a pure javascript solution but it would likely be a little too much.

Comment: Aye, but, it's of my opinion the OP would be better off learning the javascript than to become dependant on libraryA or B. If you look, there's too many people that "know jQuery but not javascript"

Comment: @SReject thumbs up on the opinion, for a beginner libraries like jQuery are step backwards...

Comment: Fair points - I have expanded a bit and added a non-jquery option.

Answer (score 1):

```
arrayImageSource= ["Image1","Image2","Image3"];

setInterval(cycle, 2000);
var count = 0;

function cycle()
{
  image.src = arrayImageSource[count]
  count = (count === 2) ? 0 : count + 1;
}​
```

Maybe something like this?

Comment: I'd suggest having all 3 images and hide/show as needed. changing the source will cause the browser to ask for a new version each time

Answer (score 1):

If you aim for good transition and effect, I suggest an image slider called "jqFancyTransitions"

Comment: Please do not suggest the use of an entire library unless quite a bit more than a single operation from it is to be used. it's of my opinion the OP would be better off learning the javascript than to become dependant on libraryA or B. If you look, there's too many people that "know jQuery but not javascript"

Comment: That's why I said "good transition and effect". Tell me how a single operation could achieve such work? He's a front-end developer. What's important is to make the website more beautiful and not simply just "to get the work done"

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        window.displayImgCount = 0;
        function cycleImage(){
            if (displayImgCount !== 0) {
                document.getElementById("img" + displayImgCount).style.display = "none";
            }
            displayImgCount = displayImgCount === 3 ? 1 : displayImgCount + 1;
            document.getElementById("img" + displayImgCount).style.display = "block";
            setTimeout(cycleImage, 1000);
        }
        cycleImage();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="img1" src="./img1.png" style="display: none">
    <img id="img2" src="./img2.png" style="display: none">
    <img id="img3" src="./img3.png" style="display: none">
</body>
</html>​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SReject/F7haV/