# Images display as broken Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm testing out a script found here

[Show images one after one after some interval of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742034/show-images-one-after-one-after-some-interval-of-time)

I don't get any errors, and it rotates the images but the images simply appear as little broken squares, which I'm assuming is the broken image icon.

I'm using google chrome, and on MAC, running mavericks. Also, all the files are on a user.local(server/host) page I created, so if I go into the directory structure in my browser, and I click on the images the images show just fine. It is only when I try to load the .html file that they appear broken. I've also tried loading images with PHP and I get the same broken image icon.

This is what I mean when I say all the files are my local computer as a server/host:

[image]

Anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

This is the script I'm using:

```
var current = 0;
var rotator_obj = null;

var images_array = new Array();
images_array[0] = "rotator_1";
images_array[1] = "rotator_2";
images_array[2] = "rotator_3";

var rotate_them = setInterval(function(){rotating()},4000);

function rotating(){

    rotator_obj = document.getElementById(images_array[current]);

    if(current != 0) {

        var rotator_obj_pass = document.getElementById(images_array[current-1]);
        rotator_obj_pass.style.left = "-320px";

    }
    else {

        rotator_obj.style.left = "-320px";

    }

    var slideit = setInterval(function(){change_position(rotator_obj)},30);

    current++;

    if (current == images_array.length+1) {

        var rotator_obj_passed = document.getElementById(images_array[current-2]);
        rotator_obj_passed.style.left = "-320px";
        current = 0;
        rotating();

    }

}

function change_position(rotator_obj, type) {

    var intleft = parseInt(rotator_obj.style.left);

    if (intleft != 0) {

        rotator_obj.style.left = intleft + 32 + "px";

    }
    else if (intleft == 0) {

        clearInterval(slideit);

    }

}


</script>

<style>

#rotate_outer {

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
    margin-top: -120px;
    margin-left: -160px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#rotate_outer img {

    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;

}

</style>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="rotating();">

<div id="rotate_outer">
    <img src="images/owl.png" id="rotator_1"  style="left: -320px;" />
    <img src="images/bee.png" id="rotator_2"  style="left: -320px;" />
    <img src="images/owl.png" id="rotator_3"  style="left: -320px;" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: right click and inspect your images. do they point to the proper url? try out that url on your browser (it is the src="" attribute)

Comment: The little broken square indeed is telling you "there is no image where you said it would be".  Just check your URL to make sure it's pointing to the right place, and everything is spelled right.

Comment: note that `images/owl.png` is a relative URL. It's unclear to me how your server is set up, but that URL refers to a subdirectory called `images` in the same directory as the html. You could use `/images/owl.png` to get an absolute path from the server's root directory. Like the others said, sounds like either the URL is bad or the server isn't configured to serve the URL.

Comment: @Matthew So if my `DocumentRoot` in my httpd.conf (apache server) file is set to a completely different path than from that of where my files are hosted, that is probably what's causing the broken images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bad url in the src attribute of the image. right click the broken image icon and inspect it (most, if not all browsers support this) and see where the url leads.

Fixing url, try one of the following:

Try adding a / in front of your image links

Try including the full path on the image including the http, also you can try excluding the http and writing //yourwebsite.com/images/foo.jpg instead and see if that fixes things.

If you work on some framework there is bound to be a base url variable which you can use instead of manually writing the url

Comment: To anyone who might be having the same problem, what I did was I clicked on the /images directory and clicked on the owl.png and bee.png images, this displayed the images on the browser, I then inspected the images as suggested and put the entire path `http://user.local/...` in the `<img src="">`

Comment: keep in mind that it would be a good practice to create an enviromental variable which holds the domain name and use that instead of hardcoding it, as you will have a hell of a time if moving the page somewhere else~